# Specify the command file location from two

Tags: linux

I have two command files with same and both of them are located in PATH folder.
This means that `which mycmd` returns two different path  like

```
$ which mycmd
/usr/local/bin/mycmd
/usr/bin/mycmd
```

How can I specify `mycmd` uses `/usr/local/bin/mycmd`(or the other)?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel reluctant to change your path, you can use an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29).

```
alias mycmd='/usr/local/bin/mycmd'
```

This is particularly useful if different commands would otherwise require differently ordered paths.

Add the statement to `.bashrc`, to prevent you from having to type it in at every shell session.

Answer (score 0):

I think that file in directory that is earlier in you PATH will take precedence.

So if your path looks like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/games/bin
```

then `/usr/local/bin/mycmd` will match before `/usr/bin/mycmd` and will be the one executed. If you want it the other way around, swap the order in your `$PATH`.